# Running a .bat file is not working in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have written a command, `pscp`, into my batch file. When I am running the .bat file, it is doing its work and fetching the files, but when I am calling it through the Selenium using Python, it shows the below error.

> pscp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

When running the batch file, below is the output it should have given.

```
C:\Users\akash.burnwal\Desktop\apr>pscp -pw <password> username@server:remote_path\count*.txt <local_path>

count_failures.txt        | 0 kB |   0.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
count_jobs_ran.txt        | 0 kB |   0.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

Below is the command that I've tried:

```
import os
os.system(r"C:\Users\akash.burnwal\Desktop\apr\apr.bat")
```

Comment: Is the path of `pspc` in `%PATH%`?

Comment: yes it is there but when i am running from jupyter notebook it is not able to take `pscp` command. is there any way to check what is the path taken in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Yes, you can print `os.environ.get('PATH')`. In IPython (in your Jupyter notebook) you can also use `%env` to get or set environment variables.

Comment: thanks Andre . now i got the issue by doing `%env`. in the PATH variable some of the directory path is not showing which is causing issue. what is the syntax for setting the path permanently to environment variables?

Comment: It's `setx <env-var> <value>`. Here `setx PATH <pspc-path>;%PATH%`. But imho is best to put those paths in code, so you don't pollute PATH and you make obvious that dependency to anyone, especially your future self.